# Constraining UITableView to the edges of its parent view without storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I'm instantiating in `viewDidLoad` and want to constrain to the edges of my view.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.rowHeight = 44;

[self.view addSubview:tableView];

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:0 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:0 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:0 constant:0].active = YES;

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:0 constant:0].active = YES;

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Doing this causes a crash/error

> 2017-08-24 11:52:25.530554-0400 objtest[61964:48549108] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for
>   ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0};
>   adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second
>   item together with a location for the first attribute creates an
>   illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location
>   attributes must be specified in pairs.'

How can I get this properly aligned using `NSLayoutConstraint` (or something better built into iOS)?

Comment: Start with the initializer specified in the class documentation perhaps (`initWithFrame:style:`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the "multiplier" to be 1 not 0 for those constraints.